# RViz is crashing in MoveIt 2 tutorials

Tags: ros2, rviz, moveit

I'm now to the first step in the [MoveIt Quickstart in RViz](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/quickstart_in_rviz/quickstart_in_rviz_tutorial.html), and the RViz process is crashing immediately. I've included the output at the end.

I should mention that I had to skip the following step in the installation section.

```
# You may want to add this to ~/.bashrc to source it automatically
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp
```

Because it would result in the following error:

```
root@Josh-LG-Gram:~# export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp
root@Josh-LG-Gram:~# ros2 launch moveit2_tutorials demo.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /root/.ros/log/2023-10-04-10-07-50-489092-Josh-LG-Gram-3563
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [1696428470.509654108] [rcl]: Error getting RMW implementation identifier / RMW implementation not installed (expected identifier of 'rmw_cyclonedds_cpp'), with error message 'failed to load shared library 'librmw_cyclonedds_cpp.so' due to dlopen error: librmw_cyclonedds_cpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, at ./src/shared_library.c:99, at ./src/functions.cpp:65', exiting with 1., at ./src/rcl/rmw_implementation_identifier_check.c:139

root@Josh-LG-Gram:~# sudo apt install ros-rolling-rmw-cyclonedds-cpp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
ros-rolling-rmw-cyclonedds-cpp is already the newest version (1.9.0-1jammy.20230908.230644).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Below is the output from trying to run the tutorial:

```
root@Josh-LG-Gram:~# ros2 launch moveit2_tutorials demo.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /root/.ros/log/2023-10-04-10-06-43-462245-Josh-LG-Gram-3398
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [rviz2-1]: process started with pid [3401]
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-2]: process started with pid [3403]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [3405]
[INFO] [move_group-4]: process started with pid [3407]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-5]: process started with pid [3409]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process started with pid [3411]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [3413]
[INFO] [spawner-8]: process started with pid [3415]
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914171015] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914396192] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment bracelet_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914411941] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment end_effector_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914414959] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment forearm_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914417313] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment half_arm_1_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914419641] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment half_arm_2_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914421589] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_base_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914424159] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_left_finger_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914426670] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_left_finger_tip_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914428721] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_left_inner_knuckle_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914431305] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_left_knuckle_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914433484] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_right_finger_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914435553] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_right_finger_tip_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914437645] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_right_inner_knuckle_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914439760] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment robotiq_85_right_knuckle_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914441961] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment shoulder_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914448578] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment spherical_wrist_1_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914450909] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment spherical_wrist_2_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1696428403.914452935] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[static_transform_publisher-2] [INFO] [1696428403.914467608] [static_transform_publisher]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-2] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-2] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-2] from 'world' to 'base_link'
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1696428403.935497563] [controller_manager]: [Deprecated] Passing the robot description parameter directly to the control_manager node is deprecated. Use '~/robot_description' topic from 'robot_state_publisher' instead.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428403.935905879] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428403.936449220] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1696428403.936491294] [mock_generic_system]: Parameter 'fake_sensor_commands' has been deprecated from usage. Use'mock_sensor_commands' instead.
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1696428403.936517681] [mock_generic_system]: Parsing of optional initial interface values failed or uses a deprecated format. Add initial values for every state interface in the ros2_control.xacro. For example:
[ros2_control_node-5] <state_interface name="velocity">
[ros2_control_node-5]   <param name="initial_value">0.0</param>
[ros2_control_node-5] </state_interface>
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428403.936526919] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428403.936546196] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428403.936553445] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1696428403.936559772] [mock_generic_system]: Parameter 'fake_sensor_commands' has been deprecated from usage. Use'mock_sensor_commands' instead.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428403.936566245] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428403.936620852] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428403.936635081] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428403.936641393] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428403.936644412] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'RobotiqGripperHardwareInterface'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428403.936647056] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428403.936649170] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428403.936654237] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428403.936655972] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'KortexMultiInterfaceHardware'
[rviz2-1] QStandardPaths: runtime directory '/run/user/0/' is not owned by UID 0, but a directory permissions 0700 owned by UID 1000 GID 1000
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428403.948348347] [controller_manager]: update rate is 1000 Hz
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428403.948550474] [controller_manager]: RT kernel is recommended for better performance
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428403.978742714] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.00504055 seconds
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428403.978826304] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'gen3'...
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428403.978836436] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.090704552] [moveit_kinematics_base.kinematics_base]: Joint weights for group 'manipulator': 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428404.129864912] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428404.144276639] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_trajectory_controller'
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1696428404.155913004] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1696428404.169177014] [joint_trajectory_controller]: [Deprecated]: "allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end" is set to true. The default behavior will change to false.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428404.170433230] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428404.170757709] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1696428404.184361770] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1696428404.186946002] [spawner_joint_trajectory_controller]: Loaded joint_trajectory_controller
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428404.189704060] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_trajectory_controller'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428404.189875882] [joint_trajectory_controller]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428404.189899737] [joint_trajectory_controller]: Command interfaces are [position velocity] and state interfaces are [position velocity].
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428404.189951477] [joint_trajectory_controller]: Using 'splines' interpolation method.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428404.192253106] [joint_trajectory_controller]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20.00 Hz.
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1696428404.204018067] [spawner_joint_trajectory_controller]: Configured and activated joint_trajectory_controller
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 3411]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 3413]
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.405309862] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.405483161] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Listening to 'joint_states' for joint states
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.406323258] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Listening to joint states on topic 'joint_states'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.407012419] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.407062073] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.407476367] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.407499835] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting world geometry update monitor for collision objects, attached objects, octomap updates.
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.407902073] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'collision_object'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.408325694] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[move_group-4] [WARN] [1696428404.408902349] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor.middleware_handle]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
[move_group-4] [ERROR] [1696428404.408932765] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor.middleware_handle]: No 3D sensor plugin(s) defined for octomap updates
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428404.560703822] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'robotiq_gripper_controller'
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1696428404.570638986] [spawner_robotiq_gripper_controller]: Loaded robotiq_gripper_controller
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428404.571867809] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'robotiq_gripper_controller'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1696428404.572023535] [robotiq_gripper_controller]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20Hz.
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1696428404.580937999] [spawner_robotiq_gripper_controller]: Configured and activated robotiq_gripper_controller
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.586495364] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'OMPL'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.593231498] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Optimal Parameterization'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.593368537] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Resolve constraint frames to robot links'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.593382214] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.593384325] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.593385725] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.593409391] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.602594248] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'STOMP'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.606896434] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Optimal Parameterization'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.606938172] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Resolve constraint frames to robot links'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.606940523] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.606942185] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.606943681] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.606945326] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.612402083] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner.joint_limits_aggregator]: Reading limits from namespace robot_description_planning
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.624843339] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Available plugins: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderCIRC pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderLIN pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderPTP
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.624883098] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderCIRC
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.626598644] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [CIRC]
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.626677780] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderLIN
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.627793919] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [LIN]
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.627825645] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderPTP
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.628686285] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [PTP]
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.628717122] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'Pilz Industrial Motion Planner'
[move_group-4] [WARN] [1696428404.628720029] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: No planning request adapter names specified.
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.689415372] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Added FollowJointTrajectory controller for joint_trajectory_controller
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.689487397] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Max effort set to 0.0
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.693025179] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Added GripperCommand controller for robotiq_gripper_controller
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.693200523] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 2 controllers in list
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.693234761] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 2 controllers in list
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.693858840] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.693885514] [move_group.move_group]: MoveGroup debug mode is ON
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.719530474] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner.move_group_sequence_action]: initialize move group sequence action
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.725342291] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner.joint_limits_aggregator]: Reading limits from namespace robot_description_planning
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.725679303] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner.joint_limits_aggregator]: Reading limits from namespace robot_description_planning
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.726730309] [move_group.move_group]:
[move_group-4]
[move_group-4] ********************************************************
[move_group-4] * MoveGroup using:
[move_group-4] *     - ApplyPlanningSceneService
[move_group-4] *     - ClearOctomapService
[move_group-4] *     - CartesianPathService
[move_group-4] *     - ExecuteTrajectoryAction
[move_group-4] *     - GetPlanningSceneService
[move_group-4] *     - KinematicsService
[move_group-4] *     - MoveAction
[move_group-4] *     - MotionPlanService
[move_group-4] *     - QueryPlannersService
[move_group-4] *     - StateValidationService
[move_group-4] *     - SequenceAction
[move_group-4] *     - SequenceService
[move_group-4] ********************************************************
[move_group-4]
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.726780875] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_context]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1696428404.726786608] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_context]: MoveGroup context initialization complete
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/ApplyPlanningSceneService'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/ClearOctomapService'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteTrajectoryAction'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPlanService'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupQueryPlannersService'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupStateValidationService'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'pilz_industrial_motion_planner/MoveGroupSequenceAction'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'pilz_industrial_motion_planner/MoveGroupSequenceService'...
[move_group-4]
[move_group-4] You can start planning now!
[move_group-4]
[INFO] [spawner-8]: process has finished cleanly [pid 3415]
[ERROR] [rviz2-1]: process has died [pid 3401, exit code -11, cmd '/opt/ros/iron/lib/rviz2/rviz2 -d /root/ws_moveit/install/moveit2_tutorials/share/moveit2_tutorials/launch/kinova_moveit_config_demo.rviz --ros-args -r __node:=rviz2 --params-file /tmp/launch_params_831_f4af --params-file /tmp/launch_params_u754irxz --params-file /tmp/launch_params_tiorpkyf --params-file /tmp/launch_params_fzwnv3fy --params-file /tmp/launch_params_12aaqfbg'].
```

When I type `dmesg`, this appears multiple times.  I see a "potentially unexpected fatal signal 11" in there which looks an awful lot like the -11 error code, above:

```
[84328.125556] Code: 74 2e 4c 8b 2f 4c 8d 77 10 4c 8b 66 08 48 89 fb 48 89 f5 4d 39 ee 74 7d 48 8b 57 10 4c 39 e2 72 2c 4d 85 e4 75 51 4c 89 63 08 <43> c6 44 25 00 00 48 8b 44 24 08 64 48 2b 04 25 28 00 00 00 75 6c
[84328.125561] potentially unexpected fatal signal 11.
[84328.125563] CPU: 15 PID: 3787 Comm: rviz2 Not tainted 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1
[84328.125565] RIP: 0033:0x7f6748709fbd
[84328.125569] Code: 74 2e 4c 8b 2f 4c 8d 77 10 4c 8b 66 08 48 89 fb 48 89 f5 4d 39 ee 74 7d 48 8b 57 10 4c 39 e2 72 2c 4d 85 e4 75 51 4c 89 63 08 <43> c6 44 25 00 00 48 8b 44 24 08 64 48 2b 04 25 28 00 00 00 75 6c
[84328.125570] RSP: 002b:00007f6700bf6100 EFLAGS: 00010246
[84328.125571] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 00007f66f80922d0 RCX: 00007f66f80ace50
[84328.125572] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007f66f807c430 RDI: 00007f66f80922d0
[84328.125572] RBP: 00007f66f807c430 R08: 00007f66f808c1e0 R09: 000000000000021d
[84328.125573] R10: 000000000000006d R11: 846bef485063031a R12: 0000000000000000
[84328.125574] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 00007f66f80922e0 R15: 00007f66f8079480
[84328.125574] FS:  00007f6700bfb640 GS:  0000000000000000
[84547.490586] misc dxg: dxgk: dxgkio_query_adapter_info: Ioctl failed: -22
[84547.492138] misc dxg: dxgk: dxgkio_query_adapter_info: Ioctl failed: -22
[84547.493281] misc dxg: dxgk: dxgkio_query_adapter_info: Ioctl failed: -22
[84547.494583] misc dxg: dxgk: dxgkio_query_adapter_info: Ioctl failed: -2
[84547.497026] misc dxg: dxgk: dxgkio_query_adapter_info: Ioctl failed: -22
[84547.498109] misc dxg: dxgk: dxgkio_query_adapter_info: Ioctl failed: -22
[84547.499136] misc dxg: dxgk: dxgkio_query_adapter_info: Ioctl failed: -22
[84547.500241] misc dxg: dxgk: dxgkio_query_adapter_info: Ioctl failed: -2
[84550.034049] rviz2[4039]: segfault at 0 ip 00007feec1864fbd sp 00007fee757f5100 error 6 in libstdc++.so.6.0.30[7feec17b3000+111000]
[84550.034060] Code: 74 2e 4c 8b 2f 4c 8d 77 10 4c 8b 66 08 48 89 fb 48 89 f5 4d 39 ee 74 7d 48 8b 57 10 4c 39 e2 72 2c 4d 85 e4 75 51 4c 89 63 08 <43> c6 44 25 00 00 48 8b 44 24 08 64 48 2b 04 25 28 00 00 00 75 6c
[84550.034065] potentially unexpected fatal signal 11.
[84550.034097] CPU: 2 PID: 4039 Comm: rviz2 Not tainted 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1
[84550.034099] RIP: 0033:0x7feec1864fbd
[84550.034122] Code: 74 2e 4c 8b 2f 4c 8d 77 10 4c 8b 66 08 48 89 fb 48 89 f5 4d 39 ee 74 7d 48 8b 57 10 4c 39 e2 72 2c 4d 85 e4 75 51 4c 89 63 08 <43> c6 44 25 00 00 48 8b 44 24 08 64 48 2b 04 25 28 00 00 00 75 6c
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I got this working by:

1. Install VcXsrv on the windows host.
2. Set my environment (~/bash.rc):

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1
```

Comment: Can you please check the `LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT` variable and set it correctly? Right now, it seems a bit weird!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

As of writing this answer, [the MoveIt 2 installation documentation](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/getting_started/getting_started.html) is focused on ROS Iron. However, it works with other versions as well. Below are some key points to keep in mind:

1. Please clone the `main` branch of `moveit2_tutorials`. However, in the case of ROS Humble, please clone the `humble` branch.
2. If `ros-rolling-rmw-cyclonedds-cpp` is creating issue, please install `ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-rmw-cyclonedds-cpp` package.
3. Please re-compile your MoveIt workspace after switching to Cyclone DDS.

The above should work as expected!

Comment: Just tried this (1. remove rolling version. 2. add iron version 3. Set RWM_IMPEMENTATION 4. Rebuild Colcon workspace).  I still got a -11.  A window opens for about .0001 seconds and then closes and that error appears.

Comment: @JoshMouch: Thanks a lot. Two things: 1. Can you please invoke RViz on your workspace without executing `demo.launch.py`? 2. To be frank, I have installed/run `moveit2_tutorials` countless times on ROS 2 (Humble, Iron) and never faced any RViz issue! I suspect something related to graphics or running it in virtualization, etc. It would be worth sharing the details of your environment so that the issue can be replicated! Thank you for your kind cooperation.

Comment: Do you just mean run "rviz2" by itself in the terminal?  That looks like this:
```
root@Josh-LG-Gram:~# rviz2
QStandardPaths: runtime directory '/run/user/0/' is not owned by UID 0, but a directory permissions 0700 owned by UID 1000 GID 1000
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: As for details of my environment, it's a brand new, fresh install of Ubuntu on Windows 11 WSL2, following the MoveIt quick start guide.  I can't think of anything interesting about it.

Comment: I think I got it.  I installed VcXsrv on the windows host. And added this to my environment:
export DISPLAY=:0
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1